# Using statement with directoryservices

Tags: active-directory, directoryservices, using-statement

Could you help me and tell if im using the "using statement" correctly in my directoryservice function that gets distingushed name from my Active Directory. I want to dispose and close objects correctly.

Code:

```
Public Function GetObjectDistinguishedName(ByVal objClass As objectClass, _  
    ByVal returnValue As returnType, _
    ByVal objName As String, ByVal LdapDomain As String, _  
    Optional ByVal includeLdapPrefix As Boolean = True) As String  

    Dim distinguishedName As String = String.Empty  
    Dim connectionPrefix = "LDAP://" & LdapDomain  

    Using entry As DirectoryEntry = New DirectoryEntry(connectionPrefix)
        Dim mySearcher = New DirectorySearcher(entry)
        Dim result As SearchResult
        Dim directoryObject As DirectoryEntry
        Select Case objClass
            Case objectClass.user
                mySearcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(|(cn=" + objName + ")(sAMAccountName=" + objName + ")))"
            Case objectClass.group
                mySearcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=group)(|(cu=" + objName + ")(dn=" + objName + ")))"
            Case objectClass.computer
                mySearcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=computer)(|(cn=" + objName + ")(dn=" + objName + ")))"
            Case objectClass.organizationalunit
                mySearcher.Filter = "(ou=" + objName + ")"
        End Select
        result = mySearcher.FindOne()

        If result Is Nothing Then 'If the search results in nothing, call for help!'
            Throw New NullReferenceException("Unable to locate the distinguishedName for the " & objClass.ToString & " : " & objName & " in the " & LdapDomain & " domain")
        End If

        directoryObject = result.GetDirectoryEntry()
        If returnValue.Equals(returnType.distinguishedName) Then
            If includeLdapPrefix Then
                distinguishedName = "LDAP://" & directoryObject.Properties("distinguishedName").Value
            Else
                distinguishedName = directoryObject.Properties("distinguishedName").Value
            End If
        End If
    End Using
    Return distinguishedName
End Function
```

Comment: What happens to the mySearcher? Does the Using statement dispose this to?

Comment: Add the code to your question, not as an external link that might be gone tomorrow.

Comment: Do you have a concrete reason to ask?? Seems good to me, as far as I can tell... do you see problems, issues??

Comment: Yes, I get error message "The server is not operational." when I search a lot in Active Directory. I think it is because there are too many connections running simultaneously. Perhaps i can solve the problem if i open and close connections properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a general rule you should always call `Dispose` on types that implement [`IDisposable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx).  Both `DirectoryEntry` and `DirectorySearcher` implement `IDisposable`.  In your code example only the first `DirectoryEntry` object gets disposed.  You need to add a using block for `mySearcher` and `directoryObject` as well:

```
Using entry As DirectoryEntry = New DirectoryEntry(connectionPrefix)
    Using mySearcher = New DirectorySearcher(entry)
        '...'
        Using directoryObject = result.GetDirectoryEntry()
            '...'
        End Using
    End Using
End Using
```

You may actually lighten the load on your server a bit by not using `GetDirectoryEntry` and instead retrieve "distinguishedName" directly from the search result in the folling way (this code is untested as I am not currently on a domain):

```
mySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("distinguishedName");
result = mySearcher.FindOne()
'...'
distinguishedName = result.Properties("distinguishedName")(0)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I have a similar method for getting the directory entry path (AdsPath), is it possible to get the path without using GetDirectoryEntry?

Comment: @EasyDot: I am not sure I understand your question. Is distinguishedName not equal to AdsPath?