# CA2000 Dispose objects before losing scope in MVC project for DirectoryEntry object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

CA 2000 Dispose objects before losing scope error displayed in Code Analysis for Directory Entry object in ASP.NET-Model View Controller project.

Directory Entry object used in the Manager class and I have disposed the Directory Entry object in finally statement. but still code analysis displays the error.

Please find the code snippet and suggest us to solve the issue.

```
public static IList<User> GetADUserDetails(string lastName)
        {
            DirectoryEntry searchRoot = null;
            DirectorySearcher search = null;
            SearchResultCollection resultCollection = null;
            SearchResult result;
            List<User> listADUsers = new List<User>();
            User listUsers = null;
            try
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(lastName))
                {
                    searchRoot = new DirectoryEntry();
                    searchRoot = ConnectLdapActiveDirectory();
                    search = new DirectorySearcher(searchRoot);

            // do something                
        }
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (searchRoot != null)
                {
                    searchRoot.Dispose();
                    searchRoot = null;
                }

            }
        }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Both `DirectoryEntry` & `DirectorySearcher` implements `IDisposable` interface, so it is preferred to use `using` statements with them for automatic disposal after the block ends. Here's short explanation about CA2000 warning (see references below for further info):

> If a disposable object is not explicitly disposed before all
>   references to it are out of scope, the object will be disposed at some
>   indeterminate time when the garbage collector runs the finalizer of
>   the object. Because an exceptional event might occur that will prevent
>   the finalizer of the object from running, the object should be
>   explicitly disposed instead.

From the reason provided above, the code should be modified like this:

```
public static IList<User> GetADUserDetails(string lastName)
{
    SearchResultCollection resultCollection;
    SearchResult result;
    List<User> listADUsers = new List<User>();
    User listUsers = null;

    try
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(lastName))
        {
            // if `ConnectLdapActiveDirectory` method returns `DirectoryEntry`, you can use this assignment
            using (DirectoryEntry searchRoot = ConnectLdapActiveDirectory())
            {      
                using (DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(searchRoot))
                {    
                    // do something                
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

NB: The possible reason that the warning issued is that `DirectorySearcher` instance doesn't have `Dispose()` method either inside `lastName` if-condition or `finally` block, hence the object kept stay in memory when `DirectoryEntry` object has disposed.

References:

[CA2000: Dispose objects before losing scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/ca2000-dispose-objects-before-losing-scope)

[Using statement with directoryservices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3421934/using-statement-with-directoryservices)

Comment: You will need to combine the two assignments to `searchRoot`: you now have (copied from the original code) a `new DirectoryEntry()` that will be replaced immediately but not disposed.

Comment: @HansKesting I don't know what `ConnectLdapActiveDirectory` method belongs to (it's OP responsibility to explain it), I know it's possible to create another `DirectoryEntry` inside `using` statement & assign `ConnectLdapActiveDirectory` then dispose it. Can you tell me what you mean "replaced immediately but not disposed" here?

Comment: `DirectoryEntry searchRoot = new DirectoryEntry()` creates a new DirectoryEntry. Then `searchRoot = ConnectLdapActiveDirectory();` replaces it by the result of that method call. So the first value is abandoned and not Disposed. Just use `using(DirectoryEntry searchRoot = ConnectLdapActiveDirectory())`

Comment: @HansKesting Makes sense to me if `ConnectLdapActiveDirectory()` returns `DirectoryEntry`. I just anticipate if `ConnectLdapActiveDirectory()` returns something else which may result in `InvalidCastException`.